# Why does a page opened via https send an http cookie when I log in?

Tags: cookies

I use Brave browser with VPN, I also set it to only allow https. When I log in to my Gmail account, I see http cookies in the security part of the Brave browser. As far as I know, http cookies are not that secure because they are vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Shouldn't it send https cookies instead when logging in?

Comment: Please describe what exactly you observe and how this leads to the conclusion you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "http cookie". There is an attribute "HttpOnly".

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies):

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it's only sent to the server.

There is another cookie attribute related to security, "Secure". The same [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) says:

> A cookie with the Secure attribute is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol. It's never sent with unsecured HTTP (except on localhost), which means man-in-the-middle attackers can't access it easily. Insecure sites (with http: in the URL) can't set cookies with the Secure attribute.

If the attribute "Secure" is not set, it does not mean that it was received via HTTP. Such cookie could be received via HTTP as well as via HTTPS.